# Neutron star material

Tags: gravity, nuclear-physics, neutrons, neutron-stars, binding-energy

A neutron star is created by the gravitational collapse of a massive star. The atoms are pushed into each other, the electrons into the protons etc. and it is held there under the existing gravitational field. What happens if you were able to remove a small amount of neutron star material and get it away from the gravitational field. Would the material stay as neutron star material or would it change to something else not that it's not subject to being crushed by gravity?

Comment: Neutron star material is unstable at low pressure. It would expand rapidly.

Comment: Individual neutrons decay to protons, electrons and anti-neutrinos  in around 12/15 mins

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/273175/2451 and links therein.